# How can I get XCode 6 to not stop execution when Debugger() is called?

Tags: c++, c, xcode, debugging

The title says it all.  The app I'm debugging has several diagnostics that call `Debugger()`.  I want it to just print the message and continue execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this is cleverly hidden.  Select the project in the project navigator.  Then menu:

Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...

Choose "Run" in the left column, then select the "Diagnostics" header on the top right.

At the bottom you'll see a checkbox for: "Legacy [ ] Stop on Debugger() and DebugStr()"